# Hanging Drywall over concrete slab

Tags: drywall

I'm in the process of enclosing my garage.  The bottom foot of one of my garage walls is a slab step.  Under the drywall on the top part is a one inch thick layer of rigid foam.  I need to cover up the bottom piece with drywall, but I'm unsure how to hang it over concrete and still be up to code.  I'm thinking of attaching 1 x 2 furring strips and hanging the drywall on those.  Is this the right solution?  Are there any moisture/insulation concerns with that method in Florida?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1x2 furring strips will work but should be pressure treated. I'd also go the extra "mile" and use green or other moisture resistant drywall.

Comment: Second this answer.  Construction glue attach a 5/8 or 3/4 treated wood plywood or wood strips.